# Use cases of methods of QueryByExampleExecutor<T> interface in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, query-by-example

What are the use cases of the methods of this interface `QueryByExampleExecutor<T>` in Spring data JPA. I have googled and found nothing more than the official documentation.

Perhaps someone can point me to the right resource with examples.

In particular, is `findAll(Example<S> example, Pagable pageable)` of that interface a simpler way to **search**, paginate, and sort?

Answer (score 7):

The Spring Data JPA query-by-example technique uses `Example`s and `ExampleMatcher`s to convert entity instances into the underlying query. The [current official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.introduction) has several useful examples. Here is my example inspired by documentation:

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private Address address;

  // … getters and setters omitted
}
```

**PersonResource.java**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersonResource {

@GetMapping("/persons/{name}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersons(@ApiParam Pageable pageable, @PathVariable String  name) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Person by : {}", name);
    Person person = new Person();                         
    person.setFirstname(name);  
    Page<Person> page = personRepository.findAll(Example.of(person), pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/persons");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: So why do we need to pass `Example.of(person)` and not person to `findAll()`. Can you please explain the reason of existence of `Examples` and `ExampleMatcher`?

Comment: because QueryByExampleExecutor has this API. did you have a chance to read attached a link on official documentation?

Answer (score 4):

From the Spring Docs for [`Example`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.12.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Example.html):

> Support for query by example (QBE). An Example takes a probe to define the example. Matching options and type safety can be tuned using ExampleMatcher.

So this class and the [`QueryByExampleExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.12.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html) interface are part of Spring Data's implementation of this *Query By Example* paradigm.

From the Wikipedia post on [Query by Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example):

> Query by Example (QBE) is a database query language for relational databases. It was devised by Moshé M. Zloof at IBM Research during the mid-1970s, in parallel to the development of SQL. It is the first graphical query language, using visual tables where the user would enter commands, example elements and conditions.

Finally, the documentation for the [`#findAll`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.12.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Example-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method that you reference states the following:

> `<S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable)` 
>   Returns a `Page` of entities matching the given `Example`. In case no match could be found, an empty `Page` is returned.

So essentially QBE represents a way of querying a relational DB using a more natural, template-based querying syntax, as opposed to using SQL, and Spring Data has an API which supports that.

Comment: So It's safe to say `example` parameter in `findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable` _can_ provide some kind of _filtering_. I still haven't seen a tutorial or example on this. +1 for the Wikipedia link though.

Comment: @wiseOne Yep, it is a way of filtering. The Wikipedia link has a DB example, but if you click on the query-by-example StackOverflow tag there are some Spring examples too.